# Does friction convert the translational energy of a rolling ball to its rotational energy when it causes a pure rolling and why does it do that?

Tags: energy, friction, rotation

Consider a solid sphere rotating with angular velocity $\omega$ is put on a rough surface so how will friction react and why does it convert the translational energy to rotational energy.

Comment: Pure Rolling implies that the point of contact is at rest ($V = R\omega$). And friction likes that, so friction wants pure rolling.

Comment: Do you mean the ball is initially *spinning* but has no linear motion in your reference frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friction provides a pair of equal and opposite forces. These forces act at the point where the surface of the ball meets the rough surface, and it is there when one surface is scraping over the other one. The force on the ball pushes one way, the force on the rough surface the ball is rolling on pushes that surface the other way. When the latter surface is connected to something big such as planet Earth then we can treat it as not moving so we normally don't worry about the second of the pair of forces. We just consider the force on the ball.

As a consequence of this force, the motion of the ball changes in two respects.

1. because there is a net force on the ball, the linear momentum of the ball must
   change.
2. because the force is not directed right through the centre of mass of the ball, it must change the amount of rotation of the ball (the technical term is that it changes the angular momentum of the ball about its centre of mass).

You should note that I have not mentioned energy yet.

But if the momentum changes, then so does the energy. The energy might go up or down, depending on what is happening. Here are the various cases.

Case A. Suppose that at first the ball is not rotating at all, but just sliding along. In this case as a result of (1) the energy associated with the translational motion goes down. As a result of (2) the energy associated with the rotational motion goes up until the rotating and forward motion are matched.
The motions are matched when the speed of the ball is such that it moves through a distance equal to its circumference in the time it takes to rotate once.
After this both the forward motion and the rotation fall, but now more gradually; the ball has stopped skidding and is rolling.

Case B. Now let's consider another case, where at first the ball is rapidly spinning but not at first moving along. In this case the force (1) will act to make the ball begin to move along, so the energy associated with the translational motion goes up at first, and the rotation slows. Eventually the skidding goes to rolling and we finish as in case A.

Case C. You can have other combinations. For example, if the ball is moving forward slowly while rapidly rotating in the reverse direction, then its foward motion will slow and stop and then it will roll backwards. You can do trick shots like this in snooker.

The main thing to note in the above is that the link between force, momentum and energy is as follows:

1. A force gives a *rate of change of momentum* so a force acting over some time will change the momentum.
2. When the point at which the force is acting moves in some way, then energy is transferred. The energy transfer is called *work* and it is equal to the product of the force and the distance, in the direction of the force, by which the point of action of the force moved. Whenever there is energy transfer, then some aspect of the physical world loses energy and another aspect gains energy, in such a way that the total energy stays constant.

In the rolling ball example the energy is mainly in the forward and circular motion of all the parts of the ball, but there is also the small random motion associated with heat, both in the ball and in the rough surface. Eventually all the energy ends up in that form.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a ball is moving purely rotationally with no translation at all.

The ball now gently lands on a horizontal surface with friction between the ball and the surface.

This friction now causes a friction force, acting opposite the direction of rotation of the ball:

$$F_f=\mu_k mg$$

where $\mu_k$ is the *kinetic coefficient of friction*.

This friction force also causes a torque $\sigma$, about the CoG of the ball (radius is $R$):

$$\sigma=F_f R$$

The torque now causes deceleration of the rotation of the ball. The angular decceleration $\alpha$ is given by:

$$\alpha=\frac{\rm{d}\omega}{\rm{d}t}$$

with:

$$\alpha=-\frac{\sigma}{I}$$

where $I$ is the moment of inertia of the ball.

So the ball's angular velocity $\omega$ decreases.

But the friction force $F_f$ also causes translational acceleration $a$:

$$a=\frac{F_f}{m}$$

---

So what we're seeing here is that the rotational kinetic energy $R$:

$$R=\frac12 I\omega^2$$

**decreases**, because $\omega$ decreases.

But the translational kinetic energy $K$:

$$K=\frac12 mv^2$$

**increases**, because $v$ increases.

**This process goes on until a state of pure rolling is achieved** when:

$$v=\omega R$$

Just how much translational kinetic energy is converted to rotational kinetic energy is a matter of fairly simple algebra.

Note that conservation of kinetic energy does not hold here because the friction causes non-conservative losses (i.e work).

Comment: For the purposes of first-order solutions, it's acceptable to ignore energy lost thru rolling friction (a very small amount).  If the ball were to "skid," then yes a lot of energy would be dissipated.

Comment: It's really easier to solve this using conservation of angular momentum